# Boot automatically into Debian instead of busybox/initrd?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, busybox, initrd

I'm using an old TS-7500 (https://www.embeddedarm.com/products/TS-7500) rugged platform for a home automation project (it was a freebie from my college) and I want to get the platform to boot into the Debian image automatically, by default, it boots into "busybox/initrd" and I have to enter the `exit` command to boot into Debian.

I want to make the system start up without any user-interaction so that if the platform power-cycles, it will start up without my assistance.

I've got a little Linux experience, but still not terribly great. Any suggestions?

Also... The `/initrd` directory looks like this:

`

```
ts7500:~# ls /initrd
bin      linuxrc-fastboot         linuxrc-usbroot  root    tmp
dev      linuxrc-nandmount        lost+found       sbin    ts7500.subr
etc      linuxrc-sdmount          mnt              shinit  usr
lib      linuxrc-sdroot           modules.tar.gz   slib    var
linuxrc  linuxrc-sdroot-readonly  proc             sys
```

`The`shinit` script prompts upon boot (into busybox) that the user has information about help. It seems that I could execute some commands from this script, if only I could save changes! Every time I've tried changing the file, the changes are lost at reboot. I've read that this is due to the busybox platform loading into RAM?

Here's what the `shinit` file looks like:

```
> # Copyright (c) 2009, Technologic Systems.
> # All rights reserved.
> 
> . /ts7500.subr
> 
> case $- in *i*)
>         stty ospeed 115200 >/dev/null 2>&1
>         echo
>         echo "Type 'tshelp' for help" esac
```

Maybe I could just add the `exit` command to this script, but again, I can't save it!!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for my particular problem!!!!

There is some documentation for the Technologic TS-7500 platform on the company's website, but my poor lack of experience missed a critical detail! They provide some information as shown in the code snippet below:

`rm linuxrc; ln -s /linuxrc-sdroot /linuxrc; save`

I misunderstood and thought that this should be entered as one single command. Turns out, I needed to enter it as three sequential commands:

```
# rm linuxrc
# ln -s /linuxrc-sdroot /linuxrc
# save
```

Additionally, these commands should all be entered in the BusyBox prompt, not Debian.

Additional documentation from Technologic:
https://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/TS-7500